# Suddenly all notifications are huge and black

Tags: gnome, notification

Suddenly all my notifications lost the "formatting" and look like this:

[image]

What I tried:

- I rebootet multiple times
- I disabled alle gnome-extensions

If I hover above them while poping up they switch to the normal appreance again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran [Bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) and cleared everything. After rebooting everything works normal now.